# powershell script to add a managed metadata column

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a powershell script that allows me add metadata column in SharePoint list. Thanks

Comment: Do you already have site columns created of type managed metadata? or you want to create that also?

Answer (score 10):

The code below is a mix of some PS code i had laying around and stuff translated from C# on the fly (so there might be some errors in there :-D)

Also, this code creates a fullblown site column in the SPWeb and adds that to the list

To start, you need a reference to the termstore, i've written 2 functions that use CA and the metadata service app's type to get a standard installation's Termstore:

```
function Get-TaxonomySessionDefault()
{
  $centralAdmin = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication} | Get-SPSite
  $session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($centralAdmin)
  return $session
}

function Get-TermStoreDefault()
{
  $session = Get-TaxonomySessionDefault
  $serviceApp = Get-SPServiceApplication | Where {$_.TypeName -like "*Metadata*"}
  $termStore = $session.TermStores[$serviceApp.Name]    
  return $termStore;
}
```

now you can use these methods to access the termstore and get a reference to a TermSet
to which to bind your new field

```
function Get-TermSet([string]$groupName, [string]$termSetName)
{
  $termStore = Get-TermStoreDefault
  return $termStore.Groups[$groupName].TermSets[$termSetName]
}
```

and using that function, we can create a function that creates a managed metadata site column in an SPWeb

```
function Create-TaxonomyField(
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web, 
  [string]$staticName, 
  [string]$displayName, 
  [string]$fieldGroup, 
  [string]$termStoreGroupName,
  [string]$termSetName
)
{
  $termSet = Get-TermSet $termStoreGroupName $termSetName

  $taxonomyField = $web.Fields.CreateNewField("TaxonomyFieldType", $displayName)

  $taxonomyField.SspId = $termSet.TermStore.Id
  $taxonomyField.TermSetId = $termSet.Id
  $taxonomyField.AllowMultipleValues = $false
  $taxonomyField.Group = $fieldGroup
  $taxonomyField.StaticName = $staticName
  $taxonomyField.ShowInEditForm = $true
  $taxonomyField.ShowInNewForm = $true
  $taxonomyField.Hidden = $false
  $taxonomyField.Required = $false

  $web.Fields.Add($taxonomyField);

  $web.Update();

  return $taxonomyField
}
```

Now all we need is a function to add the field to a list

```
function Add-FieldToList(
  [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web, 
  [string]$fieldName, 
  [string]$listTitle, 
)
{
  $list = $web.Lists[$listTitle]
  $list.Fields.Add($web.Fields[$fieldName])
  $list.Update()
}
```

**EDIT:** I am a big fan of [PowerGUI](http://powergui.org/), a great (free!) tool to write, test and debug(!!) your powershell scripts!

**EDIT:** I have modified some lines to make it work

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat blog post where this is mentioned with detailed steps and snapshots. Please refer - http://get-spscripts.com/2011/03/configuring-metadata-navigation.html

**EDIT**: There is also a blog post which shows how managed metadata column is added using Client Object model in SharePoint 2010. Replace them with Powershell scripts and you shall get your result - http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/adding-a-managed-metadata-column-to-a-list-via-sharepoint-server-2010-object-model/

Comment: Hi Deepu Nair Thanks for the reply but i'm looking for adding simple metadat columns to a list.The above link is about metadta navigation settings.Please Kindly help me out.

Comment: Hi Nair tried to do with the code but having some issue my list is creating the columns except the metadata column which is needed..here is the script i used

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the self promotion, but I have a post that shows you how to create a Managed Metadata column & add it to an existing list. Downloadable project as well: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2011/07/25/sharepoint-2010-managed-metadata-creating-managed-metadata-columns.aspx