# powershell script to add a managed metadata column

Tags: powershell

```
$webURL = "http://xxx/sites/wingtipcalculator"
$spSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webURL)
$spWeb = $spSite.OpenWeb()

$listTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"];

$spweb.Lists.Add("List4","Data information DTU",$listTemplate)

write-host "List added in the Web : " $spweb -foregroundcolor Yellow

$spList = $spWeb.Lists["List4"]
$spList.Fields.Add("Publication Date","DateTime",1)
$spList.Fields.Add("Headline","Text",1)
$spList.Fields.Add("LeadParagraph","Text",1)
$spList.Fields.Add("FullText","Text",1)
$spList.Fields.Add("ContactName","Text",1)
$spList.Fields.Add("ModifiedTest","DateTime",1)
$taxonomySite = Get-SPSite http://XXX:2010
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $taxonomySite
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
write-host "Connection made with term store -"$termStore.Name
$taxonomySession = $spWeb.site;

$termStoreGroup = $termStore.Groups["XX"];
$termSet = $termStoreGroup.TermSets["General Business Taxonomy (v1.0)"];
$TaxonomyField = $spList.Fields.Add("TaxonomyFieldType", "Test1"); 
$taxonomyField.SspId = $termStore.Id;
    $taxonomyField.TermSetId = $termSet.Id;
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

trying to use the above script but unable to cretae the required metadata column in list

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell script add a managed metadata column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27936/powershell-script-add-a-managed-metadata-column)

Comment: Agree, and see my answer

Answer (score 2):

You should get the taxonomy session of the site in which you are adding field.

```
$taxonomySite = Get-SPSite http://XXX:2010 
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $taxonomySite
```

Also try calling Update() method after you set the SSPId and TermSetID

Comment: Hi asish patel i tried doing that im getting the field but its not pointing to the term store its giving termstore is null..please help me out..

Comment: what is taxonomySession.TermStores.Count?

Comment: Thank You very much Asish Patel I have resolved with it...:-)

Comment: Please accept this as the answer, if it solved the problem, rather than leave a comment.

Comment: If it did not solve the problem, please post what you did to correct it as an answer. If Ashish's answer did help but was not complete, consider accepting his answer but adding the additional steps as a comment. The helps the community by increasing the value of your question.