# Create Content type with metadata field

Tags: powershell, content-type, managed-metadata, metadata

I made the following Powershell script to create a content type with a text field and a numeric field:

```
$url = "http://my-sharepoint-site"
$web = get-spweb $url
$ctypeName = “Content type X”

$ctypeParent = $web.availablecontenttypes["Document"]
$ctype = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($ctypeParent, $web.contenttypes, $ctypeName)
$ctype.Group = "My Content Type Group"
$web.contenttypes.add($ctype)


$web.fields.add(“Title”, "Text", $false)
$field = $web.fields.getfield(“Title”)
$field.Group = "My Column Group"
$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)
$ctype.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)
$ctype.update()

$web.fields.add(“Count”, "Number", $false)
$field = $web.fields.getfield(“Count”)
$field.Group = "My Column Group"
$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)
$ctype.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)
$ctype.update()
```

Is it possible with PowerShell to use Managed Metadata as new field type to a new content type?

Comment: Updated the question and code

Comment: Have a look at this link, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27936/powershell-script-to-add-a-managed-metadata-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it for MMS field is using XML

```
    [string]$customXMLFieldDef = @"
                        <Field
                                ID="{515bede1-b673-3d52-425v-958574685gl9}"
                                Name="SPCustomMMSField"
                                DisplayName="Custom MMS Field"
                                Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
                                ShowField="Term1033"
                                Required="False"
                                Group="Custom Site Columns">
                          </Field>
"@
```

From there you can use the following to add to your site:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb <Your Site address>
if (!$spWeb.Fields["Custom MMS Field"])
{
    $spWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($customXMLFieldDef )
    $taxonomySession = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($spWeb.Site)
    $defaultTermStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores[0]
    $secClassTermGroup = $defaultTermStore.Groups["Custom MMS Group"]
    $secClassTermSet = $secClassTermGroup.TermSets["Custom MMS"]

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$secClassField = `
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spWeb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("SPCustomMMSField")
    $secClassField.SspId = $secClassTermSet.TermStore.Id
    $secClassField.TermSetId = $secClassTermSet.Id
    $secClassField.TargetTemplate = [System.String]::Empty
    $secClassField.AnchorId = [System.Guid]::Empty
    $secClassField.Update()
}
```

You have now added the site column to your environment and pointed it at you term store.  Now you simply need to add it to a CT.

```
#Get the field
$customMMSField = $ctHubSite.AvailableFields["Custom MMS Field"]
#Create a link to the field
$customMMSFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($customMMSField)

if(!$ctHubSite.ContentTypes["Custom MMS Content Type"])
{
    write-host Creating Custom MMS Content Type
    #The id starts with the document ID (0x0101 and then a GUID for the remainder)
    $baseContentTypeID = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId("0x01010B007530C5BA0111CC49947576F6A26D0057")
    $baseCT = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($baseContentTypeID, $spWeb.ContentTypes, `
                                "Custom MMS Content Type");
    $baseCT.Group = "Document Content Types";
    #add the new CT to the site
    $spWeb.ContentTypes.Add($baseCT) | Out-Null

    #grab the new CT
    $baseCT = $ctHubSite.ContentTypes["Custom MMS Content Type"]

    #and add the new field
    $baseCT.FieldLinks.Add($customMMSFieldLink);

    #update the CT
    $baseCT.Update();
    }
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error: #Get the field
$customMMSField = $ctHubSite.AvailableFields["Custom MMS Field"] (Cannot index into a null array)

Comment: My bad.  When this was written initially it was to go into a Content Type Hub and my variables reflected that.  I missed this one when I modified for this post.  Use $spWeb.AvailableFields["Custom MMS Field"]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
  Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

  Function CreateField ([string]$weburl,[string] $centraladminurl,[string] $termstoreName,[string] $termGroupName,[string] $termsetName,[string] $fieldName,[string] $contenttypeName)

    {
      $spWeb = Get-SPWeb $weburl

      $fields = $spWeb.Fields

      $session = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $centraladminurl

      $termStore = $session.TermStores[$termstoreName]

      $group = $termStore.Groups[$termGroupName]

      $termSet = $group.TermSets[$termsetName]

      $field = $fields.CreateNewField(“TaxonomyFieldType”,$fieldName)

      $field.SspId = $termStore.Id

      $field.TermSetId = $termSet.Id

      $field.AllowMultipleValues = $true

      $field.Group = “My Content Type”

      $field.Required = $false

      $fields.Add($field)

      $contentType = $spWeb.ContentTypes[$contenttypeName]

      $taxonomyfield = $fields[$fieldName]

      $contentType.FieldLinks.Add($taxonomyfield)

      $contentType.Update()


    }

    $url = "http://siteurl"
    $web = get-spweb $url
    $ctypeName = “123New Content type X”

    $ctypeParent = $web.availablecontenttypes["Document"]
    $ctype = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($ctypeParent, $web.contenttypes, $ctypeName)
    $ctype.Group = "My Content Type Group"
    $web.contenttypes.add($ctype)
    CreateField(pass respective values values)
    $web.Update()      

  Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

In the above code, I have created function name "CreateField", which will create the taxonomy field and it will add it to the newly created content type. Pass respective values to the "CreateField" function.

Comment: thanks. But not 100% working. Can you give me a example what to fill in for $fieldName and $contenttypeName?

Comment: $fieldName - is the metadata field name and $contenttypeName -  is the name of the content type in which you want to add the metadata field.

Comment: The script returns no errors, but it creates a new field with type "single line of text" and makes it optional regardless of my true/false parameter

Comment: $field = $fields.CreateNewField(“TaxonomyFieldType”,$fieldName), this is the command which creates the field of type managed metadata field, nowhere in the code we have specified as "single line of text", so can you please check your code again.

Comment: did the code work.?